# What is the best way to implement complex layout with multiple collection view on iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface, layout

I'm implementing a complex UI for Discover screen on iOS platform.

Problem:
- Screen has 3 sections
- Each section contains a specific UICollectionView. 
- First section is a paging horizontal collection
- Second section is a scrolling horizontal collection
- Third section is a scrolling vertical collection
- When user scroll down, first and second section will moved.

My solution:
- Use Collection View with 3 sections
- First section contains 1 cell, cell contains a Paging Horizontal Controller
- Second section contains 1 cell, cell contains a Scrolling Horizontal Controller
- Third section contains multiple cells

Layout as below:

[image]

However, I think you guys have another solutions which better! Please help me to contribute this problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: `UIStackView` is your friend ;)

Comment: I just tried with `UIStackView` but I have a problem. When user scroll down 3rd section, 1st section + 2nd section will be moved by offset.

Comment: Add a container view for them maybe?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your solution. I tried but 1st and 2nd section can not move up / down by 3rd section.

Comment: Put each collection view in a containing view, then use stackview to layout the containers, rather than the collection views.